# Is there a way to allow .htaccess file in IIS windows hosting?

Tags: .htaccess, web-config

I'm using windows shared hosting with a wordpress site, and I used a theme that create .htaccess file which is not allowed in the windows hosting.

I don't need to simulate the .htaccess code, I just want to allow it to be existed not to run.

Is there a way to allow .htaccess file to be existed in IIS windows shared hosting?

for example: is there a way to allow it from web.config?
or a way to delete it automatically when existed?

Comment: What do you mean by "allowed"? Who should keep you from creating such a file if you feel like it? Certainly not the IIS server.

Comment: Some wordpress themes create .htaccess files automatically, when created, the site gives an error and stop working, then I have to delete them every time, so I need a way to allow that file or to remove it automatically.

Comment: I'd say you first need to find out what you actually mean by "the site gives an error and stop working"... What component is actually causing what? "Does not work any more" is not that much helpful...

Comment: Thank you all, I need to use wordpress template , this template create .htaccess automatically, it means that this template can not be run on windows hosting. So, is there any way to avoid this? I thought if I can allow .htaccess or ignore it, or create a code that delete it every time it created.